# How often are Azure Database Transaction Unit (DTU) averaged?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Are DTU limits always like a policeman with a speed gun who just looks at your current speed and if it is above then you're busted or is like two cameras on a highway that measure your average speed?

If it is an average how small is the window?

Comment: how can this be a opnion based ?

Comment: I'm very interested in this too - especially with respect to DTU pools (and trying to decide whether a DTU pool is worth the price for my setup). Also really curious if a single complex query run by itself in a 10DTU database would take the same time as in a 100DTU database (i.e. does DTU limit only matter when averaging out all queries).

Answer (score 1):

Your database is controlled using Resource Governor and when the queries are in need of any resource like IO,CPU,Memory after exhausting their limits..They will be in queue ..[This has been documented here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/)..

> One of the design goals of the Basic, Standard, and Premium service tiers is for Azure SQL Database to behave as if the database is running on its own machine, completely isolated from other databases. Resource governance emulates this behavior.
>
> If the aggregated resource utilization reaches the maximum available CPU, Memory, Log I/O, and Data I/O resources assigned to the database, resource governance will queue queries in execution and assign resources to the queued queries as they free up.